# Iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, getelementsbyclassname

I want to iterate over some DOM elements, I'm doing this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "myclass" ).forEach( function(element, index, array) {
  //do stuff
});
```

but I get an error:

> document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").forEach is not a function

I am using Firefox 3 so I know that both `getElementsByClassName` and `Array.forEach` are present. This works fine:

```
[2, 5, 9].forEach( function(element, index, array) {
  //do stuff
});
```

Is the result of `getElementsByClassName` an Array? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 626, accepted):

No, it's not an array. As [specified in DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), it's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (in modern browsers, at least. Older browsers returned a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)).

In all modern browsers (pretty much anything other IE <= 8), you can call Array's `forEach` method, passing it the list of elements (be it `HTMLCollection` or `NodeList`) as the `this` value:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    // Do stuff here
    console.log(el.tagName);
});

// Or
[].forEach.call(els, function (el) {...});
```

If you're in the happy position of being able to use ES6 (i.e. you can safely ignore Internet Explorer or you're using an ES5 transpiler), you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
    // Do stuff here
    console.log(el.tagName);
});
```

Comment: No need to convert it to an Array first. Just use `[].forEach.call(elsArray, function () {...})`.

Comment: It's NOT a NodeList. It's an array-like object. I don't even think it has an instance type. `querySelectorAll` method returns a NodeList though.

Comment: @MaksimVi. You're absolutely right: DOM4 specifies that `document.getElementsByClassName()` should return an [`HTMLCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection) (which is very similar but not a NodeList). Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @MaksimVi.: I wonder whether that changed at some point. I usually check these things.

Comment: @TimDown, Thanks for `HTMLCollection` tip. Now I finally can use `HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;` in my code.

Comment: @MaksimVi.: I did some research. Browser implementations did indeed change from `NodeList` to `HTMLCollection`, although I'm not sure exactly when (since 2010, anyway). Therefore `HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach` may not cover every browser you care about.

Comment: or just use `const els = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myclass"))`

Comment: @catalint: If you're able to use ES6 then yes, sure. Browser support isn't there yet for most browser-based uses.

Comment: I made the following bunch of divs: (first line just for context) `$('.behaelter_850ankuendg').css({'width': width});   

        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("behaelter_850ankuendg");
        var i = 0;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
            el.css({'left': (i*width)+'px', 'top': (-(i*100))+'%'}); i++
        });`

doesn't work (el.css not a function). What am I messing up?

Taken a bit out of context, but I didn't want to post my whole script lol

Comment: It's not the dynamic css part, it doesn't work with basic value strings either...   jQuery works in other places so it's not that.... thank you!!

Answer (score 152):

You can use `Array.from` to convert collection to array, which is way cleaner than `Array.prototype.forEach.call`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")).forEach(
    function(element, index, array) {
        // do stuff
    }
);
```

In older browsers which don't support `Array.from`, you need to use something like Babel.

---

ES6 also adds this syntax:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")].forEach(
    (element, index, array) => {
        // do stuff
    }
);
```

Rest destructuring with `...` works on all array-like objects, not only arrays themselves, then good old array syntax is used to construct an array from the values.

---

While the alternative function `querySelectorAll` (which kinda makes `getElementsByClassName` obsolete) returns a collection which does have `forEach` natively, other methods like `map` or `filter` are missing, so this syntax is still useful:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")].map(
    (element, index, array) => {
        // do stuff
    }
);

[...document.querySelectorAll(".myclass")].map(element => element.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Note: without transpilling as suggested (Babel), this is NOT compatible in IE < Edge, Opera, Safari < 9, Android browser, Chrome for Android, ...etc)
[Source: mozilla dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 67):

**Or you can use `querySelectorAll` which returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList):**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').forEach(...)
```

Supported by modern browsers (including Edge, but not IE):
[Can I use querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll)
[NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility)

**MDN:** [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Bear in mind the performance penalty over getElementByClassName

Comment: **The performance penalty is negligible** compared to other more intensive tasks like modifying DOM.
If I execute [60,000 of these in 1 millisecond](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-queryselector-by-id), I'm pretty sure it won't be an issue for any reasonable usage :)

Comment: You linked the wrong benchmark. Here is the correct one https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4076/0/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname Just ran it on my low-end phone, got 160k/s vs 380k/s. Since you mentioned DOM manipulation, here is that too https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/5705/0/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-with-foreach Got 50k/s vs 130k/s. As you see it's even slower to manipulate DOM, likely due to NodeList being static (as mentioned by others). Still neglegible in most use cases, but almost 3 fold slower nonetheless.

Comment: IE doesn't support forEach method for NodeList too. But there is a work around like using  spread operator or Array.from

Answer (score 19):

The result of `getElementsByClassName()` is not an Array, but an *array-like object*. Specifically it's called an `HTMLCollection`, not to be confused with `NodeList` ([which has it's own `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)).

One simple way with ES2015 to convert an array-like object for use with `Array.prototype.forEach()` that hasn't been mentioned yet is to use the spread operator or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');

[...elementsArray].forEach((element, index, array) => {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I feel this is really the right way to do it in modern browsers.  This is the exact use case spread syntax was created to solve.

Comment: Let me state that I am perhaps the world's most incompetent JavaScript programmer and this was the example that worked for me, out of the box, first try.  Thank you very, very much Kloptikus.

Answer (score 18):

`getElementsByClassName` returns **HTMLCollection** in modern browsers.

which is
**array-like object similar to arguments** which is iteratable by `for...of` loop see below what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) doc is saying about it:

> The **for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects**,
> including: built-in String, Array, **Array-like objects (e.g., arguments**
> or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It
> invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the
> value of each distinct property of the object.

**Javascript Example**

```
for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName("classname")){
   element.style.display="none";
}
```

**Typescript Example**

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
let i;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

  if (elements[i] instanceof HTMLElement) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Comment: Not so, according to Typescript: `error TS2488: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute, Here OP is using javascript not typescript and i have answered in according to vanilla js recommendation so in typescript it can be different solution for the problem.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute, By the way it is also working in typescript also, but you have to mention right type of variable which holds element of particular css class, so it can cast it accordingly, for detail see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621602/7719176).

Comment: This is easily the best answer and it works fine in Typescript.

Comment: `Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is not an array type or a string type.`

Comment: @NateS yes its not an array or string type, but what i have said is it's an array like objects and its true , see this MDN doc definition of [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil The code as shown doesn't compile in TypeScript, I posted the compiler error. Though the question is about JS, other commenters have said it works in TS, but it doesn't.

Comment: @NateS what you can do is get this `HTMLCollection` into the variable and declare it type `any` and it will work as it works in javascript.

Comment: @NateS typescript example also added check it in my above answer.

Answer (score 16):

Edit: Although the return type has changed in new versions of HTML (see Tim Down's updated answer), the code below still works.

As others have said, it's a NodeList.  Here's a complete, working example you can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function findTheOddOnes()
            {
                var theOddOnes = document.getElementsByClassName("odd");
                for(var i=0; i<theOddOnes.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(theOddOnes[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>getElementsByClassName Test</h1>
        <p class="odd">This is an odd para.</p>
        <p>This is an even para.</p>
        <p class="odd">This one is also odd.</p>
        <p>This one is not odd.</p>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Find the odd ones..." onclick="findTheOddOnes()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works in IE 9, FF 5, Safari 5, and Chrome 12 on Win 7.

Comment: Verified Dec 2020 that this code still works.

Answer (score 6):

for typescript I prefer iterating for

```
for(let element of Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myclass'))){
   //my code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As already said, `getElementsByClassName` returns a [*HTMLCollection*](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection), which is defined as

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface HTMLCollection {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  getter Element? item(unsigned long index);
  getter Element? namedItem(DOMString name);
};
```

Previously, some browsers returned a [*NodeList*](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodelist) instead.

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  iterable<Node>;
};
```

The difference is important, because DOM4 now defines *NodeList*s as iterable.

According to [Web IDL](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable) draft,

> Objects implementing an interface that is declared to be iterable
>   support being iterated over to obtain a sequence of values.
>
> > **Note**: In the ECMAScript language binding, an interface that is
> >     iterable will have “entries”, “forEach”, “keys”, “values” and
> >     [@@iterator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) properties on its [interface prototype object](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-interface-prototype-object).

That means that, if you want to use `forEach`, you can use a DOM method which returns a *NodeList*, like [`querySelectorAll`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-parentnode-queryselectorall).

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myclass").forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Note this is not widely supported yet. Also see [forEach method of Node.childNodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36108712/1529630)

Comment: Chrome 49 return `forEach in not a function`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Try Chromium 50

Comment: On Chrome 50 I am getting `document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich It worked on Chromium 50, and still works on Chromium 53. Maybe it wasn't considered stable enough to be shipped to Chrome 50.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the result of getElementsByClassName an Array?

No

> If not, what is it?

As with all DOM methods that return multiple elements, it is a NodeList, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 3):

This is the safer way:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) myFunction(elements[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution:

```js
Object.assign(HTMLCollection.prototype, {
  forEach(event) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, (element) => event(element));
  },
});
```

---

After that you can write like this:

```js
document
  .getElementsByClassName("disable")
  .forEach((element) => alert(element.classList[0]));
```

---

Comment: Please do some formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test I created on jsperf:
https://jsperf.com/vanillajs-loop-through-elements-of-class

The most perfomant version in Chrome and Firefox is the good old for loop in combination with document.getElementsByClassName:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('testClass'), elLength = elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < elLength; i++) {
    elements.item(i).textContent = 'Tested';
};
```

In Safari this variant is the winner:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.testClass');
elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.textContent = 'Tested';
});
```

If you want the most perfomant variant for all browsers it might be this one:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('testClass');
Array.from(elements).map(
    (element) => {
        return element.textContent = 'Tested';
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add forEach method to HTMLCollection

```
/**
 *
 * @type {Function}
 */
HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach ||
    function (callBack) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callBack(this[i])
        }
    };
```

Then your code will work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "myclass" ).forEach( function(element, index, array) {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: While this works, it is a bad practice to modify prototype.

Answer (score 0):

It does not return an `Array`, it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList).