# How to hide child elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="wpq2">
   <div class="subClass">
   <a id="linkTO" class="subClass">New Item</a>
   or
   <a class="subClass">edit</a>
   this list
   </div>
</div>
```

i want to hide all the thing except

```
   <a id="linkTO" class="subClass">New Item</a>
```

I do not have access to html , 
i have to use javascript

i tried somthing

```
var parentID = document.getElementById('wpq2');
var sub = parentID.getElementsByClassName('subClass');
var lastChild = sub[0].lastChild;
lastChild.style.display = 'none';
```

Using javascript no idea how to do

Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var parentID = document.getElementById('wpq2');
//get the first inner DIV which contains all the a elements
var innerDiv = parentID.getElementsByClassName('subClass')[0];
//get all the a elements
var subs = innerDiv.getElementsByClassName('subClass');

//This will hide all matching elements except the first one
for(var i = 1; i < subs.length; i++){
   var a = subs[i];
   a.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SWVuW/)

---

**EDIT**: The above will only hide the a element, as your text elements are not contained within specific elements then it becomes more tricky. If you are happy to effectively "delete" the HTML you don't want then you can do the following:

```
var parentID = document.getElementById('wpq2');
//get the first inner DIV which contains all the a elements
var innerDiv = parentID.getElementsByClassName('subClass')[0];
//get the HTML for the a element to keep
var a = innerDiv.getElementsByClassName('subClass')[0].outerHTML;
//replace the HTML contents of the inner DIV with the element to keep
innerDiv.innerHTML = a;
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SWVuW/1/)

Comment: or get rid of the iteration code by using `forEach`: `subs.forEach(function(sub){ sub.style.display='none'; });`

Comment: @xtofl: Your forEach code will hide them all, including the first one

Comment: thank you , but i have to remove the text "or" and "this list" also

Comment: @prash: Ok will look into that too

Comment: @prash: See my edit, it will remove the HTML you don't want rather than hide it. Is that acceptable for your requirements?

Comment: @xtofl: FYI, `forEach` wont actually work in this case, due to `subs` being a `nodeList`. [more information here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3871602/838807)

Comment: apoligies; `Array.prototype.slice.apply(subs, 1).forEach(...)`? (http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/N2H6r/)

Comment: more apologies: `...slice.call(subs, 1)...`.

Answer (score 1):

insert new html if you don't need the rest

```
document.getElementById('wpq2').innerHTML = '<a id="linkTO" class="subClass">New Item</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var parentID = document.getElementById('wpq2');
    var innerDiv = parentID.getElementsByClassName('subClass')[0];
    var subs = innerDiv.getElementsByClassName('subClass');
    subs.forEach(function (sub) { sub.style.display = 'none'; });
    document.getElementById("linkTO").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Who said what? Where?? Please don't reference comments as a part of your solution, especially when they are on other answers. They can easily be deleted

Comment: Sorry, just updated my answer. I'm still a newbie to Stack Overflow ethics, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @prash: Even if the `forEach` worked, it would have the same problem with text nodes as my original answer (pre-update)

Comment: @Trupti: The `forEach` won't work in this instance due to `subs` being a `nodeList` not an `Array`, [see here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3871602/838807)