# GetElementsByClassName - can't write the function to use the returned array

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have posted about this already, but I think my question was poorly explained. I have multiple divs with class of "popupEdit".
 I want to be able to target these using getElementsByClassName.....the result being a popup with some input field. See the code below.
I know that getElementsByClassName returns an array of all the elements with the class EditQuestion, but I have failed to write a function that works to use this array. My lack of skill (I'm a newbie). 
Could someone give me the solution so I have something I can study. Apologies for asking directly for the answer...I have tried numerous things without success.
Many thanks

HTML

```
   <button class="EditQuestion">Edit</button>
   <div class="overlay2"></div>
   <div class="popupEdit">
   <h2>Edit Question, some input box here..</h2>
   <button class="CloseBtn2">Close</button>
   </div>
```

JS

```
     window.onload = function () {

        document.getElementsByClassName("EditQuestion").onclick = function () {
         var overlay2 = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay2");
         var popupEdit = document.getElementsByClassName("popupEdit");
         overlay2.style.display = "block";
         popupEdit.style.display = "block";
       };

       document.getElementsByClassName("CloseBtn2").onclick = function () {
         var overlay2 = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay2");
         var popupEdit = document.getElementsByClassName("popupEdit");
         overlay2.style.display = "none";
       popupEdit.style.display = "none";
       };
     };
```

CSS

```
      button.EditQuestion{
       padding: 0;
       border: none;
       background: none;
       color:#A8A8A8;
       font-weight: bold;
      }

      button.CloseBtn2 {
       padding: 0;
       border: none;
       background: none;
       position:absolute;
       right:10px;
       top:5px;
      }

      .popupEdit {
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        left:40%;        
        top:30%;         
        width:600px;     
        height:150px;
        margin-top:-75px;
        margin-left:-150px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        border:1px solid #000;
        z-index:100000;      
      }

    .overlay2 {
      display:none;    
      position:fixed;  
      left:0px;        
      top:0px;         
      width:100%;      
      height:100%;     
      background:#000; 
      opacity:0.5;     
      z-index:99999;   
    }
```

Edited version - I have tried to use querySelectorAll as suggested by TJ Crowder....the querySelector works, but when I add in the for loop and change to querySelectorAll it fails....any suggestions

```
 window.onload = function () {

 document.querySelectorAll(".EditQuestion").onclick = function () {
 var overlay2 = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay2");
 var popupEdit = document.querySelectorAll(".popupEdit");
 var index;
        for (index = 0; index < overlay2.length; ++index) {
        overlay2[index].style.display = "none";
        popupEdit[index].style.display = "block";
    }
 };

 document.querySelectorAll(".CloseBtn2").onclick = function () {
     var overlay2 = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay2");
     var popupEdit = document.querySelectorAll(".popupEdit");
     var index;
        for (index = 0; index < overlay2.length; ++index) {
        overlay2[index].style.display = "none";
        popupEdit[index].style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

};

Comment: Are you want to get array of element from `classname`?

Comment: Where is the div with `EditQuestion` class? I only see a button witt that class.

Comment: Apologies....yes I mean many popupEdit classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` (on the browsers where it exists) returns a *list*, not a single element. So this line and similar:

```
overlay2.style.display = "none";
```

...fails, because the list doesn't have a `style` property.

If you just want to handle the *first* match, you can grab it via `[0]`:

```
overlay2[0].style.display = "none";
```

(That will fail if there are *no* matches, though.) Or, since `getElementsByClassName` isn't as well-supported as `querySelector`, you might prefer:

```
overlay2 = document.querySelector(".overlay2"); // Gives you the first match; note the dot
overlay2.style.display = "none";
```

Or if you want to loop through all of them, you need a loop:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < overlay2.length; ++index) {
    overlay2[index].style.display = "none";
}
```

To get the list for that loop, either use `getElementsByClassName` as you are currently (but it won't work on IE8), or use `querySelectorAll` (which will):

```
overlay2 = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay2"); // Gives you a list
```

---

> Could you show me how you would incorporate this loop into the JS function.

I don't think you want a loop; you just want to handle the specific overlay and popup related to the button, right?

I'd probably change the HTML slightly so that each group has a group div or similar around it:

```
<div class="question"><!-- Wrapper div for each question -->
    <button class="EditQuestion">Edit</button>
    <div class="overlay2" style="display: none"></div><!-- Note I've hidden ... -->
    <div class="popupEdit" style="display: none">     <!-- ...these by default -->
        <h2>Edit Question, some input box here..</h2>
        <button class="CloseBtn2">Close</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

...and use event delegation:

```
var container = document.getElementById("questions");
hookEvent(container, "click", function(event) {
    var button, group, overlay, display;

    // Find the button that was clicked, if any
    button = event.target;
    while (button && (
          button.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "BUTTON" ||
          !button.className.match(/\bEditQuestion\b|\bCloseBtn2\b/)
        )) {
        button = button.parentNode;
    }
    if (button) {
        // One of our desired buttons was clicked, find the parent
        group = button.parentNode;
        while (group && !group.className.match(/\bquestion\b/)) {
            group = group.parentNode;
        }
        if (group) {
            overlay = group.querySelector(".overlay2");
            display = overlay.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
            overlay.style.display = display;
            group.querySelector(".popupEdit").style.display = display;
        }
    }
});
```

...where `hookEvent` looks something like this:

```
function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(event) {
            var e = event || window.event;
            if (!e.target) {
                e.target = e.srcElement;
            }
            handler.call(element, e);
        });
    } else {
        throw "addEventListener or attachEvent required";
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/senahile/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/senahile/1/edit)

The great thing about event delegation is that since you're handling the event on a container, it doesn't matter how much you add or remove questions in the container, it just keeps working.

A lot of the code above is to deal with IE weirdness, and to handle the event delegation. FWIW, a good DOM library can make that all a LOT simpler for you. Here's a jQuery example:

```
$("selector for the container").on("click", ".EditButton, .CloseBtn2", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    button.closest('.question').find(".overlay2, .popupEdit").toggle(button.is(".EditButton"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. Could you show me how you would incorporate this loop into the JS function. This is the part that I am having problems with. Essentially when the page opens there will be many 'edit question buttons' and I want the user to be able to click on any of them and activate the pop up.....really appreciate the help and apologies for the need for 'spoon feeding' on this....

Comment: @GhostRider: I've updated the answer, I probably wouldn't use a loop at all.

Comment: Awesome...I am going to study your answer and try it out. Many thanks for all this work. I will let you know how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns *NodeList* or *HTMLCollection*.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("EditQuestion")[0].onclick = function () { //<-- get the first (and only?) element from the list
```

Comment: It's actually a _NodeList_ or _HTMLCollection_ which are _Array-like_ but not _Arrays_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `getElementsByClassName` to get the ,**Array of all element with that class** then :

It is something like below:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
// Do stuff with the element
console.log(el.tagName);
});

 // Or optionally
[].forEach.call(els, function () {...});
```

Answered by Tim Down on [**getElementsByClassName**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample working code for you to get started — http://jsfiddle.net/vVq7E/1.
 Also learn to use the following `getElementsByClassName` , `addEventListener`, `nextElementSibling`, `element.style` which are used in this code

```
<div class='modules'>
    <button class='edit'>Edit</button>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <p>Hello!</p>
        <button class='close'>Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

```
window.onload = function init() {
    modules = document.getElementsByClassName('modules');
    len = modules.length;
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        modules[i].getElementsByClassName('edit')[0].addEventListener('click', showOverlay);
        modules[i].getElementsByClassName('close')[0].addEventListener('click', hideOverlay);
    }
}

function showOverlay() {
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOverlay() {
    var overlays = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (overlays[i].style.display === 'block') {
            overlays[i].style.display = 'none';
            return;
        }    
 }
```

```
.modules {
    /*optional!*/
    margin:10px;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    /*optional!*/
    padding:20px;
    /*optional!*/
    background:yellow;
}
```