# Attach a plain JavaScript plugin to multiple html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Let's say I want to make a plain JavaScript plugin.

```
  var myPlainJsPlugin = (function (param1,param2) {
   /*code here*/
 });
```

How do I attach this plugin, just after the document is loaded, to all elements with the class 'elmClass', *without* jQuery?

I am talking basically about making a **plain JavaScript plugin** and using it **similar** to using a jQuery plugin:

```
$('.elmClass').jQueryPlugin();
```

I am trying to give up jQuery for a certain project.

Comment: what do you mean attach it? click, hover loaded? which event and what should it do? should it just extend the HTMLElement?

Comment: Thats not a *plugin* - its just a *function*!

Comment: On load. Unobtrusively.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking yet :)

Comment: You could take selector as a parameter, then use document.querySelectorAll to get the elements and do whatever you want... however its hard to answer without more clarification

Comment: Do you want to RUN the myPlainJsPlugin() function when the user clicks on an element with the elmClass function? Still not quite clear on exactly what you mean by "attach" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 window.onload = function(){
     var els = document.getElementsByClassName("elmClass");

     Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
           // Add code here 
           // e.g: el.onclick = doSomething();
     });
 };    `
```

`

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var elemtsWithClass = document.querySelectorAll(".elmClass");
    for(var x=0; x<elemtsWithClass.length; x++){
            elemtsWithClass[x].addEventListener("click", function(e) {}); 
    });
```