# I'm Unable to Clear the Form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Onreset-3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" class="abc"><br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" class="abc"><br><br>
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Clear">
    <script>
        function reset()
        {
            var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
            a.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to clear the username and password in the above form. I have been trying using id's but no use

Comment: Why don't you just use a standard HTML reset button?

Comment: My task is to do using functions in j.s instead of reset in html..

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array.  It returns a `nodeList`.  you have to loop over it the same but not all array functions are available for nodeLists.

Comment: By task do you mean homework?

Comment: So, where is the correction i need to do sir!!!

Comment: ofcourse it's my own task..i must be skilled in j.s..i m seeking for help

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('abc') returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
```

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.

<kbd>[MDN: getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)</kbd>

The result value is a `HTMLCollection`.

In this scenario we can iterate over the collection.

**With Javascript by Using `HTMLCollection`:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Onreset-3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Username:
    <input type="text" class="abc">
    <br>
    <br>Password:
    <input type="password" class="abc">
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Clear">
  <script>
    function reset() {
      var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
      // a = HTMLCollection
      console.log(a);
      // You can iterate over HTMLCollection.
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // You can set the value in every item in the HTMLCollection.
        a[i].value = "";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Without Javascript**

However, your form can perfectly works with a reset button.
The `<input type="reset" value="Clear">` must be inside the form tag.

Something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Onreset-3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Username:
    <input type="text" class="abc">
    <br>
    <br>Password:
    <input type="password" class="abc">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Additional Information:**

> **`HTMLFormElement.reset()`**: `The HTMLFormElement.reset()` method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same
>   thing as clicking the form's **reset button**.
>
> If a form control (such as a **reset button**) has a name or id of reset
>   it will mask the form's reset method. It does not reset other
>   attributes in the input, such as disabled.
>
> **Usage:**
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("myform").reset();
> ```

<kbd>[`HTMLFormElement.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)</kbd>

Comment: It's not an **array**.  There's a significant difference between a `nodeList` and and `array`

Comment: Sir! What for loop does here sir..i request you to explain please

Comment: @JosephMarikle, yes, you're right. In this scenario, it's a nodeList.

Comment: @ManojKarthik Updating my answer with explanation.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Actually, I was also wrong.  Apparently old browsers return nodeLists.  Modern browsers now return [HTMLCollections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).  I only just found this out myself from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: @JosephMarikle..Sure Sir...Feeling Privileged with you

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez..Thanks alot For The Information Sir

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Also, Sorry for the initially bad information of it being a nodeList.

Comment: @ManojKarthik I've updated my answer with an alternative solution by using reset button. Without javascript. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think OP is confused. He said `My task is to do using functions in j.s instead of reset in html.`. So this answer: first solution is not a reset, it removes all values independently of the initial value. And second solution is without javascript, so OP don't need this. However, OP gives you the correct answer. So OP is very confused...

Comment: I fully understand your point of view, however, my intention is to show, through an «**alternative solution**», the possibility of restoring the fields of a form with the correct use of the `<form>` and `<input>` tags. My intention is to help to the OP with any other possible solution. It's good to help others with all knowledge that you have. Anyways, in this answer I'm showing two solutions to help in this question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

native reset is better and perfectly works

```
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" class="abc"><br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" class="abc"><br><br>
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Clear">
    <script>
        function reset()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].reset();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just to add: One of the reasons this is better is that it restores the initial value of each input element, which might not be an empty string.

Comment: Yes @TimSeguine , if a `<input value="Initial value">` when you reset, it appears again `Initial value`. That's as a reset should work. Workarounds are very slow and lot of lines of code, when reset makes it automatically