# Select all img tags and give them a src

Tags: javascript

I've tried a lot of ways to fix this problem but can't figure it out.

My problem is that I try to select all `<img>` by doing

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

and then add `.src=text[x]` to it like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").src=text[x];
```

Well that doesn't work. I've also tried to use this:

```
var r = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
r.src=text[x];
```

Again, nothing. If I use this code(`immg` is the ID all the `<img>` have):

```
document.getElementById('immg').src=text[x];
```

It does work but only on the first object since it's only searching for one element with ID `immg` and not all of them.

My full code:

first function

```
function generateChar()
{
    var text = [
        "img/Water1.png",
        "img/Water2.png",
        "img/Water3.png",
        "img/Water4.png",
        "img/Water5.png",
        "img/Water6.png",
    ];
    var size = text.length;
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
    //document.getElementsByTagName("img").src=text[x];
    //document.getElementById('immg').src=text[x];
    var r = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    r.src=text[x];
    //console.log(r);
}
```

the other useful code:

```
var nbDiv = 50;
for(var i = 0; i < nbDiv; i++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var imgg = document.createElement('img');

    div.id = "d"+i ;
    imgg.id = "immg";
    imgg.className = "iimg";
    div.className = "movement timeSpan";
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(imgg);
}
```

and `generateChar()` is called under the for()

So what I would want to achieve is giving all the img a random picture(which works I only need to select the right items).

All solutions are welcome.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` give node list instead of single node. `document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src` will work

Comment: You are using `.src` on an array which won't work.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: @Jerodev it's technically an `HTMLCollection` which is array-*like* but not technically an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is an iterable list of elements.

This is what you should do:

```
let images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')

for (image of images) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length) // pick a random image URL
    image.src = text[x] // set the src to that URL
}
```

---

Also, I see you are saying:

> `immg` is the ID all the `<img>` have

It is **wrong** to use the same ID on multiple elements. Never do this! IDs should be unique. That's also why if you use `getElementById` it only returns the first element found, because it assumes that the ID you are providing is unique for that element.

You should use classes instead, like this:

```
<img class='immg'>
```

Comment: This works for me, but now i see all the img have the same images, is there a fix for that?

Comment: Yes, generate `x` inside the loop

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca can you explain how?, i don't understand where i should put it. im kinda new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add a random/list src to img tag:

```js
    // Random
    var items = ["http://placehold.jp/9062aa/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/3fb4e9/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/6fc063/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/d94949/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/f8951e/cccc00/150x100.png","http://placehold.jp/7a564a/cccc00/150x100.png"];

    $(".random-img").each(function (index) {

        var img = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
        $(this).attr('src', img);

    });
    
    // Listed
        var items2 = ["http://placehold.jp/9062aa/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/3fb4e9/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/6fc063/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/d94949/cccc00/150x100.png", "http://placehold.jp/f8951e/cccc00/150x100.png","http://placehold.jp/7a564a/cccc00/150x100.png"];

    $(".list-img").each(function (index) {

        var img2 = items2[index % items2.length];
        $(this).attr('src', img2);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Random images from array</h1>
    <img class="random-img" />
    <img class="random-img" />
    <img class="random-img" />
    <img class="random-img" />
    <img class="random-img" />
    <img class="random-img" />
    
    
    <h1>Listed images from array</h1>
    <img class="list-img" />
    <img class="list-img" />
    <img class="list-img" />
    <img class="list-img" />
    <img class="list-img" />
    <img class="list-img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get a random image text from the array and use that in the loop.

```js
function getRandomImage(img) {
  var images = [
    "img/Water1.png",
    "img/Water2.png",
    "img/Water3.png",
    "img/Water4.png",
    "img/Water5.png",
    "img/Water6.png",
  ];
  var rand = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  return rand
}

(function() {
  var nbDiv = 50;
  for (var i = 0; i < nbDiv; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var imgg = document.createElement('img');
    div.id = "d" + i;
    div.className = "movement timeSpan";
    imgg.id = "immg" + i;
    imgg.className = "iimg";
    randomImg = getRandomImage();
    imgg.src = randomImg;
    imgg.alt = randomImg;
    div.appendChild(imgg);
   // console.log(imgg);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
}())
```

```css
.iimg {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
}
```

A jQuery version of same thing

```js
function getRandomImage(img) {
  var images = [
    "img/Water1.png",
    "img/Water2.png",
    "img/Water3.png",
    "img/Water4.png",
    "img/Water5.png",
    "img/Water6.png",
  ];
  var rand = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  return rand
}

(function() {
  var nbDiv = 50;
  for (var i = 0; i < nbDiv; i++) {
    randomImg = getRandomImage();
    var div = $('<div/>')
      .addClass("movement timeSpan")
      .attr('id', "d" + i);
    var imgg = $('<img/>').addClass("iimg")
      .attr('id', "immg" + i)
      .attr('alt', randomImg)
      .attr('src', randomImg);
    imgg.appendTo(div);
    $('body').append(div);
  }
}())
```

```css
.iimg {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```