# How can I make sure I get a collection of HTML nodes/elements which I can use forEach on?

Tags: javascript

So I just learned that it makes a difference whether I use

```
document.querySelectorAll('selector')
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selector')
```

The latter cant be iterated over with .forEach. This is probably because the latter returns an array-like object, while the first one returns a nodelist.

Now I read that some browsers return an array-like object when using 
document.querySelectorAll('selector')
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp

I'm not even sure if this problem applies to me, since I'm using a webpack based framework which uses Babel7 to transpile my Code to ES2015. But I would like to make sure that my code works on as many browsers as possible, and therefore it would be nice to know if there is a JS method to retrieve elements from the DOM which makes sure of that.

And on a sidenote, could someone point me to the piece of documentation explaining lists in JS? I couldnt find much, only the doc about arrays. Is a list just an alias for an array in JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: maybe you should take a look at [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/from)

Comment: Also, there are no `Lists` in JavaScript per se. An array in JavaScript is kind of like a List/Stream in other Languages, so it is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and `getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

The recent development seems to be that all array methods were added to `NodeList`s, while the `HTMLCollection` did not change for years, so I'd try to work with `NodeList`s as they are up-to-date, and provide `.forEach` and others.

I'd write:

```
 for(const el of document.querySelectorAll('.some-class'))
    //...
```

> But I would like to make sure that my code works on as many browsers as possible, and therefore it would be nice to know if there is a JS method to retrieve elements from the DOM which makes sure of that

For sure older browsers don't have newer features, no matter what new feature you use. However thats not your problem, Webpack handles that for you, just make sure to add the necessary polyfills.

> And on a sidenote, could someone point me to the piece of documentation explaining lists in JS?

There ain't Lists in JS, there is just a coined term called *arraylike objects*, which are objects that contain numeric keys and that do have a `.length`, however they do not inherit from `Array`. For some reason `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection` are such arraylike objects.