# Loop through an object array and change HTML elements of same class

Tags: javascript

Is there a good way to iterate through an array of objects and apply those properties to multiple html elements with same classname?

I hope my example show more specific what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks in advance!

```js
var myObject = [{
    width: 100,
    text: "Hello World",
    bgColor: '#f00',
  },
  {
    width: 20,
    text: "Hi World",
    bgColor: "#0f0",
  }
];
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
console.log(divs);

myObject.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var x = arrayItem.width;
    var y = arrayItem.text;
    var z = arrayItem.bgColor;
    divs.style.width = x + '%';
    divs.innerHTML = y;
    divs.style.backgroundColor = z;
});
```

```css
.contain {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  padding: 20px;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.one:first-child {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 80%;
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hello World", have red background and 100% width.</span></div>
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hi World", have green background and 20% width.</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at looping through the input, or using the width / text/ bgColor properties. Please post what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE] - Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service

Comment: I did not succeed with looping. I have now added my failed code that I seek help with. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over `myObject`, but also to apply current index of the loop to your `divs` element array.

```js
var myObject = [{
    width: 100,
    text: "Hello World",
    bgColor: '#f00',
  },
  {
    width: 20,
    text: "Hi World",
    bgColor: "#0f0",
  }
];
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
myObject.forEach(function (arrayItem, index) {
  if (index < divs.length) {
    var x = arrayItem.width;
    var y = arrayItem.text;
    var z = arrayItem.bgColor;
    divs[index].style.width = x + '%';
    divs[index].innerHTML = y;
    divs[index].style.backgroundColor = z;
  }
});
```

```css
.contain {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  padding: 20px;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.one:first-child {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 80%;
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hello World", have red background and 100% width.</span></div>
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hi World", have green background and 20% width.</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are simply selecting `divs` which is an array and not selecting the nested `div` elements within it properly: `divs[0];divs[1]` etc.

If the amount of divs is dependent on the object children than a better way would be to generate the divs with JS rather than have them on the HTML to begin with:

- html:

```html
`<div class="contain" />
```

- js:

```
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("contain")[0];

myObject.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    var x = arrayItem.width;
    var y = arrayItem.text;
    var z = arrayItem.bgColor;
    div.style.width = x + '%';
    div.innerHTML = y;
    div.style.backgroundColor = z;
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```

also adding a cleaner format of this code using [object deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
myObject.forEach(function ({width, text, bgColor}) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = `${width}%`;
    div.innerHTML = text;
    div.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37941811/2813224) has trouble with edge cases such as mutation and `.length` property when applied in a loop. The newer method is far better:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
```

Apply `.forEach()` method to the NodeList returned from the statement above then refer to the array of objects and their properties on each iteration by using `.forEach()` second parameter which is the current index number of the NodeList. Keep in mind that `divs` is a NodeList of divs and that the first parameter of `.forEach()` represents the current div of the NodeList not the object in the array of objects.

```
 divs.forEach((node, index) => {...
   ...const x = cfg[index].width... /* cfg[index] the object at the 
   current index in the array of objects */
   ...node.style.width = x... //node is the current div
```

```js
const cfg = [{
    width: 100,
    text: "Hello World",
    bgColor: '#f00',
  },
  {
    width: 20,
    text: "Hi World",
    bgColor: "#0f0",
  }
];
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".one");
//console.log(divs);

divs.forEach((node, index) => {
  const x = cfg[index].width;
  const y = cfg[index].text;
  const z = cfg[index].bgColor;
  node.style.width = x + '%';
  node.textContent = y;
  node.style.backgroundColor = z;
});
```

```css
.contain {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  padding: 20px;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.one:first-child {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 80%;
}

span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hello World", have red background and 100% width.</span></div>
  <div class="one"><span>Should only read "Hi World", have green background and 20% width.</span></div>
</div>
```