# How to use mouseover effect to change the background color?

Tags: javascript, html

I have lots of small squares which have a class of "newDiv". I want to change their background color to black when mouse cursor are on them. However, I want them to stay the same(backgroundcolor black) even when mouse cursor is out. I'm trying to make my code work but I always get a syntax error or it does not work at all.

I've altered the code, tried to fix syntax etc.

```
black = true;
let tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');



tiles.forEach(tile => {
tile.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  if(black){
  tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
}) 
}
```

Uncaught syntax error missing ) after argument list
tiles.forEach is not a function.

Comment: Maybe `e.target..style.backgroundColor = "black";`

Comment: Didn't work. When i solve my syntax error,I get: forEach is not a function error.

Comment: Because tiles is not an array. try to console tiles and see

Comment: @tosyn, why don't you simply use the `pseudo` class `:hover` on `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `tiles` isn't an array. It looks like one but it is actually a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

You can fix this by either converting to `Array` with `Array.from()`:

```js
let tiles = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv'));
```

Or using a `for` loop instead:

```js
for (const tile of tiles) {
  tile.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked for me.
And as @Omer said tiles is not an array.

```
var black = true;
var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');

for(var tile of tiles){
tile.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  if(black){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
}
);
}
```

Comment: Since I'm a beginner I do not know this kind of loop very well. What is tile of tiles? Is it another variable that we used to store this loop's output?

Comment: This will store each element of tiles you can check the explanation here too(for...in statement) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 0):

Because You acctually missed an ')'; It would be better if you use arrow function :)

```
let black = true;
let tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');

tiles.forEach(tile => {
tile.addEventListener('mouseover', e =>{
  if(black){
    tile.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
}) 
})
```

In addition, as written [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach?answertab=active#tab-top) - you used an html collection an not an array.

Comment: Because it's actually an "html collection" and not an array.
You should use: 
tiles = Array(tiles) before.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` results in an HTMLCollection, which cannot be iterated with a forEach(). Try using a simple for-Loop or jQuerys $.each()-Function. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/b6Lfkcrt/) is a fiddle.

```
let tiles  = document.getElementsByClassName('newDiv');

for (let i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
    tiles[i].style.backgroundColor = "black"});
}
```