# "document.getElementsByClassName" found elements but can not access

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I have a realy hard problem that I couldn't find any solution in Internet

I used `document.getElementsByClassName` to access one `HTML Element` by It's class, my element is `filterRow` of `dxDataGrid`:

```
 var filterRowElement = document.getElementsByClassName("dx-datagrid-filter-row");
                console.log(filterRowElement);
                console.log(filterRowElement.length);
```

My Problem is: The first `console.log` return `HTMLCollection` with length = 1 but the second return 0 (I tried to get length to access `filterRowElement[0]`).

I've tried  `console.log(filterRowElement[0])` and got `undefined` too

This is screen shoot:
[image]

I don't know why, it is the first time I got this problem

Please give me some advise. Thank you!

**THANK YOU, I THINK MY PROBLEM IS `DXGRID FILTERROW ELEMENT` IS CONSECUTIVELY CHANGE SO I CAN'T ACCESS OLD ELEMENT**

**UPDATE**

I don't know why but Using Jquery save Me (may be not alway true)

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    var getfilterRowElement = $(".dx-datagrid-filter-row");
                    console.log(getfilterRowElement[0]);
                }, 3000);
```

Result:

[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: no. foreach got empty, I tried but not working so I asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated: One reason why you might got a `0` for the second line, and a `1` for first line is:** you print out `filterRowElement.length`, and it is true at that time, it was `0`.  When your event cycle is over, your framework (React, Angular, etc) updated the page (either after your actions or before your actions in the next event cycle). Now `console.log` prints out the whole structure and when you look at it in the debugger, now it is `1`.

In order to solve this problem, I had to do something like this before:

```
setTimeout(() => {  

  doSomething();

}, 0);
```

So now you are waiting for the next event cycle so that your page is "constructed" or "updated".

If it is a static page, I was able to get `1` for both cases and able to access it:

Do you mean

```
console.log(filterRowElement);
```

gave you an object with `length` being `1`, and then

```
console.log(filterRowElement.length);
```

gave you `0`?

The following works:

```js
arr = document.getElementsByClassName("foo-bar");

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
arr[0].innerHTML = "hello world";

arr[0].style.background = "orange";
arr[0].style.display = "inline-block";
arr[0].style.padding = "1.2em";
arr[0].style.borderRadius = "6px";
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar"></div>
```

`getElementsByClassName` is live... is your page being changed meanwhile?  Try `document.querySelectorAll(".foo-bar")` instead:

```js
arr = document.querySelectorAll(".foo-bar");

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
arr[0].innerHTML = "hello world";

arr[0].style.background = "orange";
arr[0].style.display = "inline-block";
arr[0].style.padding = "1.2em";
arr[0].style.borderRadius = "6px";
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, It is the first time I got this Problem, I Usualy use `arr[0]` like you but no error happened.

Comment: right, `getElementsByClassName` is live... is your page being changed meanwhile?  Try `document.querySelectorAll(".foo-bar")` instead.

Comment: @DavidLink please see top of answer

Comment: It not `foreach` because of empty array return. Thank you for support

Comment: I use Jquery. using Jquery save me !

Comment: setTimeOut include Jquery may may be a temporary solution. Thank @nopole

Comment: Update: must place function inside setTimeOut 1000 put in `onInitialized`. thank you again

Comment: I can now access It and all of It's child element. xD

Comment: Wait a second, if you have to wait a whole second, then maybe you are doing it when the DOM is not ready? You should put the code near end of closing of `body` tag, or wrap everything in DOM ready, like how you do `$(function(){  })` in jQuery. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I still put everything in $(document).ready(). thank you for your advice.