# remove element javascript with classename

Tags: javascript

1. when I remove this with id it works but when I tried with className it didn't work

```
    const remov= document.createElement('a');
    remov.classList='clsx';
    remov.textContent='X';
    remov.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
    remov.onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById('Div1').remove();    }
```

1. this is my code  im trying to remove the element that i've created with id 'Div1' emphasized text

```
const lista = document.getElementById('list');

eventlisteners();

function eventlisteners(){
  document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', yrlist);
}

//function

function yrlist(e){

    e.preventDefault();  
    var textare =document.getElementById('textar').value;


    const li= document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent=textare;
    li.classList='clsli';
    li.setAttribute("id", "Div1");

    const remov= document.createElement('a');
    remov.classList='clsx';
    remov.textContent='X';
    remov.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
    remov.onclick = function (){
      document.getElementById('Div1').remove();
    }

    li.appendChild(remov);

    lista.appendChild(li);

}
```

Comment: because there is only one element for `id` and there might be many elements with same `classname`. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `getElementById` returns *single* element while `getElementsByClassName` returns *list of elements*. So you need to iterate through this list. And remove each element.

For example you can do this using loop:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("clsx");
for(var x=0; x < elements.length; x++) {
    elements[x].remove();
}
```

Comment: You can also use method from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37941811/3515645

Answer (score 0):

`remov.classList = 'clasx';` is just wrong. The `classList` member is actually a `DOMTokenList`, not a string. As such, it has functions of it's own. Rather than trying to set this member, you need to use the `add` function it contains.

I.e
`remov.classList.add('clsx');`

It seems that clicking on the element will have the effect of removing it. This is functionality you've given it at creation time. There's a better way to go about this. Rather than trying to find the element, (which must be identifiable in some manner) why not just have the element remove itself? If you connect the action and the event using `AddEventListener`, rather than by overwriting a member of the element yourself, a neat thing happens - the function that gets called behaves as though it was a part of the element that triggered it, and so the `this` keyword refers to itself. It's a huge help, but for the uninitiated, can be a real headache.

```
const removeMe = document.createElement('a');
removeMe.classList.add('clsx');
removeMe.textContent = 'X';
removeMe.addEventListener('click', function(evt){ this.remove(); }, false);
li.appendChild(removeMe);
```

Comment: thanks but also I want to delete all element with that class like  <li>