# Vanilla Javascript Ajax request will not pass parameter to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-8

My Ajax request will not successfully pass my "Id" parameter from javascript to my controller action method. I know the value is there in my javascript when debugging, but the controller always show null...

Update: I've also tried adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the controller action method, but same thing... It hits the controller method successfully, but the id is null..

Debugging, right here, my Id has the value of '2'.... but the controller still gets null......:
[image: not null in js]

[image]
My Html view:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model.CartList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Product.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductFragranceName</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductWeightName</td>
                    <td>@item.Price.Value.ToString("c")</td>
                    <td><button type="button" data-cartid="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger delete_from_cart" data-requesturl="@Url.Action("RemoveCart", "Cart", new { Area = "" })"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

My javascript:

```
//Define Namespace
var Cart = Cart || {};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (docEvent) {

    let cartDeleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete_from_cart');

    cartDeleteButtons.forEach(deleteButton => {
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let cartId = deleteButton.dataset.cartid;
            let cartRemoveRequestURL = deleteButton.dataset.requesturl;
            Cart.RemoveFromCart(cartId, cartRemoveRequestURL);
        })
    });
}); // end doc ready

Cart.RemoveFromCart = function (id, requestURL) {
    // Create the XMLHttpRequest object.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Initialize the request
    xhr.open("POST", requestURL, true);
    // Set content type
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    // Send the request with data to post
    xhr.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            id: id
        })
    );
    // Fired once the request completes successfully 
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        // Check if the request was a success
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 201) {
            // Get and convert the responseText into JSON
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}
```

My controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveCart(int id)
{
    var dbCart = await _dbContext.ShoppingCarts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(sc => sc.Id == id);
    if (dbCart != null)
    {
        _dbContext.ShoppingCarts.Remove(dbCart);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: so, the request is sent, and a response is received, but the response is not as expected?

Comment: The request is sending, but it will not send my Id parameter. parameter is always null, I'm not sure why

Comment: but you are sending a post with an object of {Id: 1} but your controller is not looking for an object but an int of id.   maybe change the post to a delete and change the controller action to a delete.  (decorate it with [HttpDelete({Id}]

Comment: oh, so the request is faulty? have you checked the HTML in the browser to see if the value of `data-cartid="@item.Id"` is correct?

Comment: @BryanDellinger how do I pass just the id and not a stringified object?

Comment: `let cartId = parseInt(deleteButton.dataset.cartid);`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, my content type needed to be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and I needed to just pass one value like so (thank you @Bryan Dellinger for that idea:

```
 xhr.send('id='+id);
```

This post helped me:
[AJAX: How to send a simple parameter by POST in vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264198/ajax-how-to-send-a-simple-parameter-by-post-in-vanilla-js)
Working JS:

```
//Define Namespace
var Cart = Cart || {};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (docEvent) {

    let cartDeleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete_from_cart');

    cartDeleteButtons.forEach(deleteButton => {
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let cartId = parseInt(deleteButton.dataset.cartid);
            let cartRemoveRequestURL = deleteButton.dataset.requesturl;
            let itemRow = deleteButton.closest('tr');
            Cart.RemoveFromCart(cartId, cartRemoveRequestURL, itemRow);
        })
    });
}); // end doc ready

Cart.RemoveFromCart = function (id, requestURL, itemRow) {
    // Create the XMLHttpRequest object.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Initialize the request
    xhr.open("POST", requestURL);
    // Set content type
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Send the request with data to post
    xhr.send('id='+id);
    // Fired once the request completes successfully 
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        // Check if the request was a success
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Get and convert the responseText into JSON
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(response.message);
            itemRow.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            alert('Error removing item from cart');
        }
    }
}
```