# Filling a div with line number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to rewrite a poem and I would love to add the line numbers (just the multiple of 3).
Is there any way to fill that `span` automatically instead of writing number by number by hand? Also I would need to restart the count for every different poem.

Thanks.

```css
#poem {margin:20px 20vw}
.riga{float:right}
p{margin:0;padding:0;display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=poem>
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><span class=riga>3</span><br><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><span class=riga>6</span><br><br>

<p>La gente che per li sepolcri giace</p>
<p>potrebbesi veder? già son levati</p>
<p>tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".</p><span class=riga>9</span><br><br>

...
</div><br><br>

<div class=poem>
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><span class=riga>3</span><br><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><span class=riga>6</span><br><br>

<p>La gente che per li sepolcri giace</p>
<p>potrebbesi veder? già son levati</p>
<p>tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".</p><span class=riga>9</span><br><br>

...
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add every line in a element like p or div ? if add every line a element you can do it from easy way.

Comment: @H.T yes surely I can

Comment: Ok I will write an example code in answer post ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".poem").forEach(poem => {
  let n = 0;
  poem.querySelectorAll("span.riga").forEach(sp => {
    n += 3;
    sp.innerHTML = n;
  });
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".poem").forEach(poem => {
  let n = 0;
  poem.querySelectorAll("span.riga").forEach(sp => {
    n += 3;
    sp.innerHTML = n;
  });
});
```

```css
#poem {margin:20px 20vw}
.riga{float:right}
```

```html
<div class="poem">
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

<p>La gente che per li sepolcri giace</p>
<p>potrebbesi veder? già son levati</p>
<p>tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

...
</div><br><br>

<div class="poem">
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

<p>La gente che per li sepolcri giace</p>
<p>potrebbesi veder? già son levati</p>
<p>tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @fraction. How would I restart the count if I have different poems and I always want to start from 3?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) you can find all the `<span>` elements with class name of `riga`. The using [`Array.from().forEach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach) you can iterate through all the items where you can add dynamic values to each of the `<span>` elements with [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

See the example - which does not require **jQuery**:

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('riga');
const value = 3;

Array.from(elems).forEach((e, i) => {
  e.innerHTML = value * (i + 1);
});
```

```css
#poem {margin:20px 20vw}
.riga{float:right}
```

```html
<div id=poem>
    Ora sen va per un secreto calle,<br>
    tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,<br>
    lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    "O virtù somma, che per li empi giri<br>
    mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,<br>
    parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    La gente che per li sepolcri giace<br>
    potrebbesi veder? già son levati<br>
    tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    E quelli a me: "Tutti saran serrati<br>
    quando di Iosafàt qui torneranno<br>
    coi corpi che là sù hanno lasciati.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    Suo cimitero da questa parte hanno<br>
    con Epicuro tutti suoi seguaci,<br>
    che l’anima col corpo morta fanno.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    Però a la dimanda che mi faci<br>
    quinc’entro satisfatto sarà tosto,<br>
    e al disio ancor che tu mi taci".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    E io: "Buon duca, non tegno riposto<br>
    a te mio cuor se non per dicer poco,<br>
    e tu m’ hai non pur mo a ciò disposto".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    "O Tosco che per la città del foco<br>
    vivo ten vai così parlando onesto,<br>
    piacciati di restare in questo loco.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    La tua loquela ti fa manifesto<br>
    di quella nobil patrïa natio,<br>
    a la qual forse fui troppo molesto".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

    Subitamente questo suono uscìo<br>
    d’una de l’arche; però m’accostai,<br>
    temendo, un poco più al duca mio.<span class=riga></span><br><br>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @norbitrial! What if I want to restart the count from 3 at every different poem on the same page?

Comment: @Federico Then I would reset the variable called `value` to `3` like `value = 3` and call again the `forEach`. But most probably wrapping into a function would be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.riga').filter( function(index) {
    return $(this).text((index + 1) * 3);
})
```

```js
$('.riga').filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).text((index + 1) * 3);
})
```

```css
#poem {margin:20px 20vw}
.riga{float:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=poem>

  <p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
  <p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
  <p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

  <p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
  <p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
  <p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

  <p>La gente che per li sepolcri giace</p>
  <p>potrebbesi veder? già son levati</p>
  <p>tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".</p><span class=riga></span><br><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
 //alert($( ".riga" ).closest( ".riga" ).val());
 var lineNumber=0;
 $('.riga').each(function(i, obj) {
   //alert($(obj).closest('.riga').text());
   lineNumber=lineNumber+3;
   $(obj).closest('.riga').text(lineNumber);
   
});
```

```css
#poem {margin:20px 20vw}
.riga{float:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=poem>
Ora sen va per un secreto calle,<br>
tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,<br>
lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri<br>
mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,<br>
parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

La gente che per li sepolcri giace<br>
potrebbesi veder? già son levati<br>
tutt’i coperchi, e nessun guardia face".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

E quelli a me: "Tutti saran serrati<br>
quando di Iosafàt qui torneranno<br>
coi corpi che là sù hanno lasciati.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

Suo cimitero da questa parte hanno<br>
con Epicuro tutti suoi seguaci,<br>
che l’anima col corpo morta fanno.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

Però a la dimanda che mi faci<br>
quinc’entro satisfatto sarà tosto,<br>
e al disio ancor che tu mi taci".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

E io: "Buon duca, non tegno riposto<br>
a te mio cuor se non per dicer poco,<br>
e tu m’ hai non pur mo a ciò disposto".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

"O Tosco che per la città del foco<br>
vivo ten vai così parlando onesto,<br>
piacciati di restare in questo loco.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

La tua loquela ti fa manifesto<br>
di quella nobil patrïa natio,<br>
a la qual forse fui troppo molesto".<span class=riga></span><br><br>

Subitamente questo suono uscìo<br>
d’una de l’arche; però m’accostai,<br>
temendo, un poco più al duca mio.<span class=riga></span><br><br>

...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Example code, add span automatically:

```js
const dv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (let j = 0; j < dv.length; j++) {  
  const ps = dv[j].getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (let i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {  
    (i+1)%3== 0 && i>1  ? ps[i].innerHTML   =ps[i].innerHTML  +'<span class=riga>'+(i+1)+'</span>':0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=poem>
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><br>

</div>


<div id=poem>
<p>Ora sen va per un secreto calle,</p>
<p>tra ’l muro de la terra e li martìri,</p>
<p>lo mio maestro, e io dopo le spalle.</p><br>

<p>"O virtù somma, che per li empi giri</p>
<p>mi volvi", cominciai, "com’a te piace,</p>
<p>parlami, e sodisfammi a’ miei disiri.</p><br>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks @H.T works perfectly! What if I want to restart the count at every different poem from 3?

Comment: @Federico , Dude check it!