# Several Elements with same Classes . but i can get only first one , why?

Tags: html, jquery, list, class, innerhtml

i have several tables with same class names ,
these tables are created from php code via loop .
like this

```
<?php 
$tableCount = 100;
$i=rand(1,999);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tableCount; $i++) {
echo "<table class='tables'>";
echo "<tr class='myTr'>";
echo "<td  class='myTD'>";
echo $i;
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

so we have 100 tds with different content ,
the problem for me is here : 
when the loop creates on page . and when i want to get all innerHtml or html() of all Td's class 
the compiler brings me first html() of td .

my jquery code :

```
var getclass = $(".myTD").html();
```

when i want to change the contents or remove or somethings ; i can do this.
for example :
for changing all contents of all td's with same class :

```
 $(".myTD").html("changed contents");
```

but i want to list . all html() of all td's with same class 
my output should be like this :

```
lists  outputs


  1,     14
  2,     188
  3,     20
  4,     2
  5,     99
  6,     11
  .,      .
  .,      .
  100,    73
```

and to end .
 but . my input gets me  firs content ;

how can i solve that . plz :(

**note this i want to do this with jquery or javascript. no php or server side .**

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to loop.

```
$(".myTD").each(function(i) {
    console.log(i, $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: thanks for you reply friend ,i think its true. but how can i list that instead of console.log in a new div?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the body of the function. Like `$("#newdiv").append(...)`

Comment: i have input. i want to : when $("#input").val() == $("#input").each(function() {
    $(this).html();
});
the td with founded val style will changes. but its not working  .and when i tried with this :  $("#input").val() == $(".myTD").html() , its brings me first value of td ,

Comment: `var x = $("#input").val(); $(".myTD").each(function() { if ($(this).html == x) { do something }})`