# How do I enable a disabled checklist in Jekyll using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll, liquid

I just need a checkbox that is clickable when rendered. It seems as though if I create a checkbox using markdown, it does not offer the option to toggle it.

Jekyll

```
- [ ] Mercury
- [ ] Venus
- [ ] Earth
```

I tried using JavaScript but it doesn't seem to be working.

JS

```
const checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName(".task-list-item-checkbox");
checkbox.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

[image]

HTML

```html
<ul class="task-list">
    <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Mercury</li>
    <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Venus</li>
    <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Earth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements so try to iterate through the result. Probably [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things what I found:

1. Once using `getElementsByClassName` you should pass the class name only without `.`, so try instead as `.getElementsByClassName('task-list-item-checkbox')`.
2. By definition [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does not return only one item but instead:

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s).

Based on my comment you can try as the following:

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('task-list-item-checkbox');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function (e) {
  e.removeAttribute('disabled');
});
```

```html
<ul class="task-list">
  <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Mercury</li>
  <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Venus</li>
  <li class="task-list-item"><input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="disabled">Earth</li>
</ul>
```

I think the above mentioned code snippet gives you the idea where to start once you want to remove `disable` class from your `input` elements.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this in the future, using JQuery works as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.task-list-item-checkbox').prop("disabled", false); 
});
```