# How can I invoke all instances of a class name in a function?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to cause all elements with the same class name ("Cappy") to change color when this function is invoked, but the only way I know how to invoke all of them is by writing out a line with the variable (myPara) and an index number for each one, and as there are many of them this seems clumsy. Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
function mouseoverCaroline(){
    var myPara = document.getElementsByClassName("Cappy");
    myPara[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    myPara[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    myPara[0].style.color = "black";
    myPara[1].style.color = "black";
    myPara[0].style.borderColor = "#94a0b4";
    myPara[1].style.borderColor = "#94a0b4";
}
```

Comment: Do a loop over them?

Comment: you need to use `for` loop or `forEach` loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
function mouseoverCaroline(className) {
    var myPara = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    Array.from(myPara).forEach(element => {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      element.style.color = "black";
      element.style.color = "black";
      element.style.borderColor = "#94a0b4";
      element.style.borderColor = "#94a0b4";
    });
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="mouseoverCaroline('Cappy')">Click Me</button>
<div class="Cappy">Div 1</div>
<div class="Cappy">Div 2</div>
<div class="Cappy">Div 3</div>
<div class="Cappy">Div 4</div>
<div class="Cappy">Div 5</div>
<div class="Cappy">Div 6</div>
```