# JavaScript foreach failed

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a JS foreach function like below:

**Edit: my minimal reproducible example**

```js
var liArray = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");
liArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.getAttribute("data-code").substring(0, 2) == 15) {
    console.log("success");
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="151" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="152" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="153" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="154" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="155" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item>
    <div data-code="156" class="listItem">example</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Than I got **150** times of `success` in my console. But when I changed `console.log` to `item.className = "disabled"`. Like:

```
liArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.getAttribute("data-code").substring(0, 2) == 15) {
    item.className = 'disabled';
  }
});
```

It turns out that only half of (**75**) the items have class `disabled`.

I have no idea what's going wrong with my code.
Hope someone can help, thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please show more context. Here are two possibilities that most likely: 1. You're running this function twice; 2. There are duplicates in your `liArray`.

Comment: FYI: If you have `data-*` attributes you can use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) property. For example: `item.dataset.code` is the same as your `item.getAttribute("data-code")`.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry for my neglect, I have added more details about this question.

Comment: @Reyno Thanks for your information! The ```data-code``` here is self-defined data, so this method can't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Comment: @Reyno Thank you, it helps me learn about what ```HTMLCollection``` may cause some problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a new className, existing item is removed from the collection which mutates the array. This causes "confusion" in loop.

```js
const foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

Array.from(foos).forEach((foo, i) => {
  foo.className = 'bar';
  console.log(`Array length: ${foos.length}, current index: ${i}`);
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li class='foo'>Foo 1</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 2</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 3</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 4</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 5</li>
</ul>
```

Therefore you should **add** a new class instead of replacing existing one with:
`item.classList.add('disabled');`

```js
const foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

Array.from(foos).forEach((foo, i) => {
  foo.classList.add('bar');
  console.log(`Array length: ${foos.length}, current index: ${i}`);
});
```

```html
<ul>
<li class='foo'>Foo 1</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 2</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 3</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 4</li>
<li class='foo'>Foo 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: However, the OP could just do what you are doing and use `Array.from(foos).forEach(...)`. `foos` will change but not the array you are calling `forEach` on.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, which has no `forEach`.

Use the normal `for` loop:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the HTMLCollection for me! In my case, the problem seems to lie in change ```className``` directly, which cause confusion in loop, like Samuli has mentioned. But thank you anyway for sharing your insight :)