# Javascript foreach function

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following code:

```
var arAddresses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClsAnschrift");
arAddresses.forEach(element => console.log(element.innerHTML));
```

and I get the following error:
*Uncaught TypeError: arAddresses.forEach is not a function*
What is the Problem?

Comment: Try using `document.querySelectorAll(".ClsAnschrift");`

Comment: Try `var arAddresses = document.querySelectorAll(".ClsAnschrift");` instead

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach

Answer (score 1):

use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var arAddresses = document.querySelectorAll(".ClsAnschrift");
arAddresses.forEach(element => console.log(element.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div class="ClsAnschrift">1</div>
<div class="ClsAnschrift">2</div>
<div class="ClsAnschrift">3</div>
```

The problem with [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is (as stated in the docs)

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns **an array-like object** of all child elements...

array like objects have no `forEach` functionality

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working because when you try to select elements using `document.getElementsByClassName`, it returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not an array, so you need to convert it into Array first and then apply forEach on it.

Convert into array using: `Array.from(variable)`

Use it this way:

```js
var arAddresses = document.getElementsByClassName("ClsAnschrift");
Array.from(arAddresses).forEach(element => console.log(element.innerHTML));
```

Answer (score 1):

HTMLCollection does not work with foreach, you can use "for ... of" instead.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("ClsAnschrift");
for (const element of list) {
  console.log(element.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div class="ClsAnschrift">a</div>
<div class="ClsAnschrift">b</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `arAddresses` is a HTMLCollection. Browsers doesn't support using forEach on HTMLCollection. You can use for loop to iterate over nodeList or you can make array from the nodeList and then use forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Array.from(arAddresses).forEach(element => console.log(element.innerHTML));
```