# How to change background color using .getElementsByClassName in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No matter how I try it, I can't make it work. If I use `.getElementById`, it works... but I need to target multiple `divs` so I need to use `.getElementsByClassName`.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function changeBgColor(color){
        document.getElementById("background1").style.background = color;
    }
 
    function changeBackground(color){
        document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work").style.background = color;
    }
```

```css
  #background1{
        background: #c0c0c0;
        padding: 50px;
    color: #fafafa;
    }

    .background2{
        background: #ff7f50;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .background3{
        background: #555;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<h4>First example</h4>

    <div id="background1"><p>My background color will change.</p></div>

    <button onclick="changeBgColor('#222');">This function will work, no problem</button>
    
    <br><br>
    
<h4>Second example</h4>
    
    <div class="background3 pls-work"><p>My background color and my sibling's won't.</p></div>
    
    <div class="background2 pls-work"><p>I am the sibling</p></div>

    <button onclick="changeBackground('#222');">This will not work</button>
```

I've been searching everywhere but I can't find one where they use `class` instead of `id`.

I would appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing wrong with this.

Comment: Since you are using `getElementByClassName` it will be accessed by array. you need to do like `document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")[0].style.background = color;` or some loop

Comment: I don't know where you've searched, but [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is the MDN doc about `getElementsByClassName` method, and should be within the first 3 results if you search for the method name in Google. Anyway, you've got multiple answers pointing you the same direction, so accept one of them and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try With this,

first get that element in variable and the loop on it.

```
function changeBackground(color){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.background=color;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this! This is exactly what I need. Although there's a lot of helpful answers below, I don't know how to use them cause I'm not yet good with JavaScript... so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an “array-like object” of elements which you need to iterate over - as opposed to `getElementById` which returns a single element.

Check this out:

```js
const changeBgColor = () => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('color-me');
  const color = document.querySelector('input').value;
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
};
```

```html
<p class='color-me'>Color me!</p>
<p>Can't change me..</p>
<p class='color-me'>Me too!</p>
<input type=color />
<button onclick=changeBgColor()>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")` returns an `HTMLCollection` of elements not a single element. You need to iterate over the collection and set the style property on each element.

See [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871602)

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a collection (NodeList) object, see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). To do what you want to do, you'll have to do the following:

```js
function changeBackground(color) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements.item(i).style.background = color
    }
}
```

See the docs as listed above for more information on how to iterate over this collection.

Answer (score 1):

**getElementsByClassName** returns the list of elements , so you can do it two ways

1.mentioning index value in javascript like below snippet

```js
function changeBgColor(color){
        document.getElementById("background1").style.background = color;
    }
 
    function changeBackground(color){
        document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")[0].style.background = color;
document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work")[0].style.background[1] = color;
    }
```

```css
  #background1{
        background: #c0c0c0;
        padding: 50px;
    color: #fafafa;
    }

    .background2{
        background: #ff7f50;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .background3{
        background: #555;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<h4>First example</h4>

    <div id="background1"><p>My background color will change.</p></div>

    <button onclick="changeBgColor('#222');">This function will work, no problem</button>
    
    <br><br>
    
<h4>Second example</h4>
    
    <div class="background3 pls-work"><p>My background color and my sibling's won't.</p></div>
    
    <div class="background2 pls-work"><p>I am the sibling</p></div>

    <button onclick="changeBackground('#222');">This will not work</button>
```

2. Do iterate over the elements of particular class and add a background color to it

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeColor() {
  let cols = document.getElementsByClassName('col1');
  for(i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    cols[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
//maybe type script gives error about style just use //@ts-ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to change the `background-color` of the **first element**?

I **prefer** to use `querySelector`

**ES5**

```js
function changeBackground(color) {
    document.querySelector(".pls-work").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

But if you want to apply **all the elements**, use `getElementsByClassName` and `forEach`

```js
function changeBackground(color){
    document.getElementsByClassName("pls-work").forEach(e => {
        e.style.backgroundColor: color;
    });
}
```

**Notice:** if you want to change **only** `background color`, use `backgroundColor`